# Undefined index: name ERROR on external file inside div using load function

Tags: javascript, php, load

Am using following code to load external file inside div

```
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("#load_home").on("click", function () {
                                $("#zaladuj").load("comments.php");
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

           <a href ="#zaladuj" id="load_home"> load</a>

                    <div id="zaladuj">

                    </div>
```

that works fine
in main page i used `$_GET['name']` to get name value and i need to pass this value to external file that is been loaded inside div , but unfortunately doesn't works

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\1video_new_template_TEST\comments.php on line 34 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0180243864{main}( )..\comments.php:0 ">
```

any help i need to pass value to file that is loaded inside div

i used this method to get value in main page 
`http://localhost:8080/single.php?name=102`

```
   $_GET['name']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this to pass the query string to file. if you have the `$_GET['name']` in your URL as query string, then you can do this

```
 $("#zaladuj").load("comments.php?name=<?=isset($_GET['name'])?>");
```

eg: output will be like this

```
 $("#zaladuj").load("comments.phpname=102");
```